# Book-recommendations "Profinite Groups"

Tags: group-theory, book-recommendation, profinite-groups

I started studying Profinite Groups a few weeks ago. I'm using the book "Profinite Groups" by Wilson as a basis, but the book is not clear enough sometimes (probably because I'm studying it for the first time). Classify a book as good or bad is subjective, so I would just like book-recommendations for me to analyze.

Comment: Try this review http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-04/S0273-0979-01-00914-4/S0273-0979-01-00914-4.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This [document](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/Lenstra-Profinite.pdf) provides a real good and short introduction. It has been written by Hendrik Lenstra (now emeritus professor at the Univ. of Leiden, Netherlands).